# Acquisition, Sibling Folder

Tags: plone

http://www.example.com/de/dienstleistungen/demos returns http://www.example.com/de/demos if demo is in http://www.example.com/de, fine, thats acquisition.

Now I have this: 
http://www.example.com/de/dienstleistungen/demos returns http://www.example.com/de/produkte/demos as demo is in http://www.example.com/de/produkte.
Thats nice, but what is the reason that Plone takes the sibling "produkte" of folder "dienstleistungen" to find "demos". What I expect is something like "Page not found. Maybe you are looking for .... demos ..."

The ZMI Error Log says

```
Exception Type  NotFound 
Exception Value http://www.example.com/de/dienstleistungen [ /demos ]
```

Comment: Did you move the "demo" page from "dienstleistung" to "produkte"?

Comment: Strange thig is that you are getting a NotFound error *and* acquisition.

Comment: If you moved the "demo" part, plone.app.redirector leaves a reference on the old place and redirects you directly to the new place. I has nothing to do with acquisition. But indeed, I would expect a "301" (raise redirect??).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to plone.app.redirector. The object was indeed moved.

Comment: Should I post this as an answer? Or should we investigate more, because it's really strange that you get those two Exceptions.

Comment: For me its OK to know that Plone remembers the old path to the object.  I think the topic is of interest, even with the question left open why despite a NotFound Error the redirect ist made. Thank you for caring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you moved the `demo` part from `http://www.example.com/de/dienstleistungen/demos` to `http://www.example.com/de/produkte/demos` plone automatically adds a reference from the old place to the new place, of the moved item. If you now try to access the old place, plone redirects you directly to the new place.

This is implemented in [`plone.app.redirector`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.redirector/)

Quote from the readme:

"Bring dead links back to life! plone.app.redirector knows where your content used to be and can bring you to its new location when content moves."